# Undefined index for an input that works when radio is selected

Tags: php

So I have a question textbox that appears after you select a checkbox, now the checkbox and the questions that appear both have statements to check if they're left empty, now when you select one of the checkboxes for gender, and leave the question blank, it all works correctly, and if you don't select a checkbox it gives the error that the checkbox isn't checked, but it will also give an error saying "Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\testfile.php on line 54"

I did try some research before posting this, and none of the solutions I could find really matched up to my problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Income Program</title>
<style>
.male-question1 {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 35px;
}

#male:checked ~ .male-question1 {
  display: block;
}
.female-question1 {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 35px;
}

#female:checked ~ .female-question1 {
  display: block;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 650px;
}
</style>
</head>
<div>
<form name="frm1" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male"/>
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <div class="male-question1">
        <label for="gendertext">Please enter your height and weight (ie. 6'2 and 175 lbs)</label> <br>
        <textarea id="gendertext" name="gendertext"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="female-question1">
        <label for="gendertext2">Please enter your marital status (ie. Single, Married, Divorced)</label> <br>
        <textarea id="gendertext2" name="gendertext2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
</div>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $error_msg= array();
        if(!isset($_POST['gender'])){
            $error_msg[] = "ERROR: No Gender selected.";
        }
    $selected_radio=$_POST['gender']; //THE ERROR
    if ($selected_radio=='Male') {
        if($_POST['gendertext']==""){
            $error_msg[] = "ERROR: Please Answer Gender Question";
        }
    }
    if ($selected_radio=='Female') {
        if($_POST['gendertext2']==""){
            $error_msg[] = "ERROR: Please Answer Gender Question";
        }
    }
    $gendertext=$_POST['gendertext'];
    $gendertext2=$_POST['gendertext2'];

    if (isset($error_msg) && count($error_msg) == 0) {
        echo "Gender: ".$_POST['gender']."<br>"."<br>";
        echo "Your textbox answer:" . " " . $gendertext . $gendertext2 ."<br>"."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Submitted Successfully";
    }
    else{
        foreach ($error_msg as $result) {
            echo $result;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The code above should run and replicate the problem, if you submit with a box checked, it works, if you submit with everything filled out, it works, if you submit with no box checked, it gives the error.

Comment: Checkboxes/radios don't exist until they've been selected or changed. You need to use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). Add the rest of the if checks inside an else belong to your first if

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you detect that `$_POST['gender']` is not set, you need to skip over the rest of the code that tries to use it.

```
if(!isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $error_msg[] = "ERROR: No Gender selected.";
} else {
    $selected_radio=$_POST['gender']; //THE ERROR
    if ($selected_radio=='Male') {
        if($_POST['gendertext']==""){
            $error_msg[] = "ERROR: Please Answer Gender Question";
        }
    }
    if ($selected_radio=='Female') {
        if($_POST['gendertext2']==""){
            $error_msg[] = "ERROR: Please Answer Gender Question";
        }
    }
}
```